Tangent of a Rational Bezier Curve
I'm currently practicing some Bezier math (i'm not the best at it) but i'm experiencing an issue when trying to calculate the tangent of a rational Bezier Curve.
for context, this is my normal Rational Bezier calculation that works without any issue (based of both Pomax's primer on Bezier curves and Freya Holmér's video
Here is my normal and working code for the Rational Bezier curve
float CalculateCubic(float t, float[] points, float[] weights)
{
    float t2 = t * t;
    float t3 = t2 * t;

    float[] f = {
        weights[0] * (-t3 + 3 * t2 - 3*t + 1),
        weights[1] * (3 * t3 - 6 * t2 + 3 * t),
        weights[2] * (-3 * t3 + 3 * t2),
        weights[3] * (t3)
    };
    
    float basis = f[0] + f[1] + f[2] + f[3];
    
    return (f[0] * points[0] + f[1] * points[1] + f[2] * points[2] + f[3] * points[3]) /basis;
}

after which, I tried to create a function that changes the point's polynomial to their derivatives to get the tangent (or velocity):
float CalculateCubicTangent(float t, float[] points, float[] weights)
{
    float t2 = t * t;

    float[] f = {
        weights[0] * (-3 * t2 + 6 * t - 3),
        weights[1] * (9 * t2 - 12 * t + 3),
        weights[2] * (-9 * t2 + 6 * t),
        weights[3] * (3 * t2)
    };

    float basis = f[0] + f[1] + f[2] + f[3];

    return (f[0] * points[0] + f[1] * points[1] + f[2] * points[2] + f[3] * points[3]) / basis;
}

However, the basis this calculates is most often 0 or a very low number (I assume caused by a rounding error). causing it to return NaN or Infinity most of the time
So i'm wondering what I'm doing incorrectly/ how I should actually approach this problem? any resources on this part are also welcome!

If t or weights are zeroes - you will get those. Return zero whenever you get near zero basis.

Does Gradient Of Bezier Curve At Given Point help?

Did you read the Derivatives portion of the link you posted? (https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#derivatives) You seem to have just taken the derivative of each of the four polynomials, but the article mentions that there should also be new weights derived from the previous weights. (I don't know the math well enough to be sure this is the issue or not.)

As mentioned: your derivative code needs updated weights, but the rational factor is also a function of t so you'll need to apply the quotient rule: A rational bezier curve is a function of the form f(t)/g(t) so the derivative is (f'(t)g(t) - f(t)g'(t)) / g(t)²

Remember that the rational factor is also a function of t, so you'll need to apply the quotient rule. A rational bezier curve is a function of the form:
f(t)
---
g(t)

so the derivative is:
f'(t)g(t) - f(t)g'(t)
---------------------
        g(t)²

So we need to know three things:

the divisor, which is trivial (it's just your basis variable, squared),
f'(t), which we already know (because Bezier derivatives are trivial to compute), and
g'(t), which we don't know yet.

We do know that g(t) is a sum of functions, and the derivative of a sum is the same as the sum of derivatives, so you should be good to go for updating your code to computing the correct derivative.
